# Umbraco: display a module in another module

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

I use the version 4 of Umbraco, and wondering if there is a way to render a module from an other module.

say

```
Root
=> Folder1
=>=> Page1
=>=>=> PageLayout
=>=>=>=> MainContentZone

=>=>=>=>=> MyMainModule

=>=>=>=>=>=> MyChildModule1
=>=>=>=>=>=> MyChildModule2
=>=>=>=>=>=> ...
=>=>=>=>=>=> MyChildModuleX
```

I would like to iterate over child modules from MyMainModule and display them all.
Something like this

```
@{
    var myLayoutHelper = new LayoutHelper(this);
    var modules = myLayoutHelper.CurrentModules;
}

@foreach (var mod in modules)
{
    <div>
        @myLayoutHelper.RenderModule(mod)
    </div>
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can call an other macroScript from a macroScript

```
@foreach(var mod in modules) 
{
    @RenderPage("~/MacroScripts/Mod-Detail.cshtml", mod.Id);
}
```

and then in the Mod-Detail page you can pick up the id like this:

```
int myId = PageData[0];
```

**Update:**

For those using Umbraco v6 in MVC modus try

```
@Html.Partial("PartialName")
@Html.CachedPartial("PartialViewName", model:myModel, cachedSeconds:60, cacheByPage:true, cacheByMember:false,   viewData:AViewDataDictionary)
@Umbraco.RenderMacro("MacroAlias")   // to render a macro
```